# Erasing content of textboxes upon hidding them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, textbox

I have an html program in which I have a checklist.  When I click on an item in the checklist it displays a text box and when I uncheck the item the text box hides.  How do I set it up so that when I uncheck an item is clears the contents of the checkbox or at the very least the id value referenced by the text box is set to a null value?

Below is my code:

```
<html lang="en"  >
<head>

        <script src="jStorage/json2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jStorage/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jStorage/jstorage.min.js"></script>


<body>

<form action="">

<font size=2><table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=100%><tr>
<td width='40%' valign='center' align='right'>Notifications :&nbsp;</td>
<td align='left'>
<!--- -->
<input type="checkbox" id="notification_1" value="Billing" class="master_enable_cb" name="master">Billing
<div class="master">
    <input type="text" id="notification_1_info" name="master">
</div>
<br>
<!--- -->
<input type="checkbox" id="notication_2" value="Address" class="address_enable_cb" name="address">Address
<div class="address">
<input type="text" id="notification_2_info" name="address">
</div>
<br>
<!--- -->
<input type="checkbox" id="notification_3" value="Phone" class="phone_enable_cb" name="phone">Phone Number
<div class="phone">
    <input type="text" id="notification_3_info" name="phone">
</div>
<br>
<!--- -->
<input type="checkbox" id="notification_4" value="Other Urgent of Special Request" class="other_enable_cb" name="other">Other Urgent/Special Notes or Requests
 <div class="other">
    <input type="text" id="notification_4_info" name="other">
</div>
<br>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('input.master_enable_cb').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    $(this).next('div.master').show();
  else
    $(this).next('div.master').hide();

}).change();

$('input.address_enable_cb').change(function(){
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    $(this).next('div.address').show();
else
    $(this).next('div.address').hide();
}).change();

$('input.phone_enable_cb').change(function(){
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    $(this).next('div.phone').show();
else
    $(this).next('div.phone').hide();
}).change();

$('input.other_enable_cb').change(function(){
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    $(this).next('div.other').show();
else
    $(this).next('div.other').hide();
}).change();
});
</script>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let me see if I got it right: when the user clicks the checkbox, you want to clear all the input values?

Comment: yes I want to input to be cleared out of the textbox.

Comment: After each `if...else` block, you could try this `$('input[type=text]').val('')`

Comment: my next question is in this code.  How do I change the size of the text boxes?

Comment: I don't really know what you are trying to accomplish, but do you want to change the size of the element programatically? I suggest you add the size attribute to the html input element, like this `<input type="text" id="notification_3_info" name="phone" size=50>`. Notice the ' size=50`. That does the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can erase the value of your text inputs with `$(ITEM_SELECTOR).val('');`

Looking at your code you could modify each of your lines that look like

```
else
    $(this).next('div.other').hide();
}).change();
```

to be

```
else {
    $(this).next('div.other').hide();
    $(this).next('div.other').find('input[type=text]').val('');
}
}).change();
```

I would change the whole thing a little bit and reduce the amount of JS code by doing something like this around each of those HTML element groups though:

```
<div class="form_field">
    <input type="checkbox" id="notification_1" value="Billing" class="toggle_cb" name="master">Billing
    <div class="master">
        <input type="text" id="notification_1_info" name="master">
    </div>
</div>
```

*Note the `.form_field` container around the HTML block.*  This helps scope things a little better and gives you more navigational options in jQuery (everything is unified under that parent).  I would do this for each item and then change the javascript to one block like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('div.form_field > input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).next('div').show();
        }
        else {
            $(this).next('div').hide()
                .find('input[type=text]').val('');
        }
    }).change();
});
```

This changes the amount of code you have to write (or rewrite) which is a good mindset to try to adopt.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function changeElement(element, type) {
        element.on('change', function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).next('div.' + type).show();

                return;
             }

            $(this).next('div.' + type).hide();
            $(this).find('input[name=' + type + ']').val('');
        });
    }

    changeElement($('input.master_enable_cb'), 'master');
    changeElement($('input.address_enable_cb'), 'address');
    changeElement($('input.phone_enable_cb'), 'phone');
    changeElement($('input.other_enable_cb'), 'other');

});
```